installing google chrome for puppeteer sharp using docker in ECS
I need puppeteer sharp in my .net project, i need google chrome and i am using the following docker file in ECS , but i am getting following error
[91mgpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
Please find my docker file -
#####################
#PUPPETEER RECIPE based on https://github.com/hardkoded/puppeteer-sharp/issues/1180#issuecomment-1015532968
#####################

FROM node:slim as build-image
ENV PUPPETEER_SKIP_CHROMIUM_DOWNLOAD true
ARG FUNCTION_DIR
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install gnupg wget -y && \
    wget --quiet --output-document=- https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | gpg --dearmor > /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/google-archive.gpg && \
    sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list' && \
    apt-get update && \
    apt-get install google-chrome-stable -y --no-install-recommends && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
######################
#END PUPPETEER RECIPE
######################
ENV PUPPETEER_EXECUTABLE_PATH "/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable"


The error gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found, occurs when there's an issue with the GPG key download process. It can happen if the URL for the signing key is incorrect, or if the download is interrupted.
Try this dockerfile with added default keyring path:
#####################
#PUPPETEER RECIPE based on https://github.com/hardkoded/puppeteer-sharp/issues/1180#issuecomment-1015532968
#####################

FROM node:slim as build-image

ENV PUPPETEER_SKIP_CHROMIUM_DOWNLOAD true
ARG FUNCTION_DIR

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y wget gnupg --no-install-recommends

# Download Google's Linux signing key and add it to the trusted GPG keys
RUN wget -q -O - https://dl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | gpg --dearmor -o /usr/share/keyrings/google-linux-archive-keyring.gpg

# Add the Google Chrome repository
RUN echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/google-linux-archive-keyring.gpg arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list

# Update package lists and install Google Chrome
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y google-chrome-stable --no-install-recommends && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

######################
#END PUPPETEER RECIPE
######################
ENV PUPPETEER_EXECUTABLE_PATH "/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable"



this command is also giving the same error, is it related to any proxy settings or firewall ?

Probably can be because of proxy: if you have a proxy server you must use that proxy in dockerfile too, smth like:
ENV http_proxy=http://your-proxy-url:port ENV https_proxy=http://your-proxy-url:port
If you have firewall - ensure that Google domains are whitelisted/not blocked.

Also you can try to manually get the keys from environment where you use the dockerfile, for example: wget https://dl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub
